# PHP: Form emailing displaying some fields, not others?

Tags: php, forms

This isn't particularly my domain. I'm helping a friend and I've been attempting to logic out  the issue through common sense and Google, but I can't figure it out.

In short: Friend has a form on his website. Form goes through a PHP script and emails him the results whenever someone fills it out. It has worked fine for awhile. He recently added some new fields and now all of a sudden some of the fields do not return results through the PHP script when submitted via the form.

Here is the HTML for the form:

```
        <div id="contact-area">

            <form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="left"><label for="Name">Full Name:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="Name" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="left"><label for="EMT">EMT #:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="EMT" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="left"><label for="NREMT">NREMT #:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="NREMT" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="left"><label for="Email">Email:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="Email" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="left"><label for="Phone">Phone:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="Phone" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="left"><label for="Address">Full Address:</label></td>
                        <td><textarea name="Address" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>            
                        <td class="left"><label for="Program">Program(s):</label></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" value="EMT NCCR" name="Program"/><label>EMT NCCR</label><br />
                        <input type="radio" value="Paramedic NCCR" name="Program"/><label>Paramedic NCCR</label><br />
                                    <input type="radio" value="10 hours ConEd" name="Program"/><label>10 hours ConEd</label><br />
                                    <input type="radio" value="Snowbird EMS Conference" name="Program"/><label>Snowbird EMS Conference</label><br />
                                    <input type="radio" value="AHA ACLS" name="Program"/><label>AHA ACLS</label><br />
                                    <input type="radio" value="AHA PALS" name="Program"/><label>AHA PALS</label><br />
    </tr>

                        <tr>                
                        <td class="left"><label for="nccrtraining">Desired NCCR Training:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" value="Online" name="nccrtraining" /><label>Online</label><br />
                            <input type="radio" value="DVD" name="nccrtraining"/><label>DVD</label><br  />
                        <input type="radio" value="USB" name="nccrtraining"/><label>USB Thumbdrive</label></td> 
                    </tr>  
                    <tr>
                        <td class="left"><label for="Operating">Operating System:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" value="Windows" name="Operating" /><label>Windows</label><br />
                            <input type="radio" value="Mac" name="Operating"/><label>Mac</label></td>

                    </tr>   
                    <tr>
                        <td class="left"><label for="emt20hournccpcoursedate">EMT 20-hour NCCP Course Date:</label></td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="radio" value="September 26th, 2015 - 12:30PM" name="emt20hournccpcoursedate" /><label>September 26th, 2015 - 12:30PM</label><br />
            <input type="radio" value="October 17th, 2015 - 12:30PM" name="emt20hournccpcoursedate" /><label>October 17th, 2015 - 12:30PM</label><br />
                        <input type="radio" value="November 14th, 2015 12:30PM" name="emt20hournccpcoursedate" /><label>November 14th, 2015 12:30PM</label><br />
                        <input type="radio" value="December 5th, 2015 8:00AM" name="emt20hournccpcoursedate" /><label>December 5th, 2015 8:00AM</label><br />
                        <input type="radio" value="December 5th, 2015 10:30AM" name="emt20hournccpcoursedate" /><label>December 5th, 2015 10:30AM</label><br />
                       <input type="radio" value="December 5th, 2015 1:00PM" name="emt20hournccpcoursedate" /><label>December 5th, 2015 1:00PM</label><br />
    </tr>
    <tr>                

</tr>   
    <tr>
                        <td class="left"><label for="paramedic30hournccpcoursedate">Paramedic 30-hour NCCP Course Date:</label></td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="radio" value="July 17th, 2015 - 8:30AM" name="paramedic30hournccpcoursedate" /><label>July 17th, 2015 - 8:30AM</label><br />
            <input type="radio" value="August 7th, 2015 - 8:30AM" name="paramedic30hournccpcoursedate" /><label>August 7th, 2015 - 8:30AM</label><br />
                        <input type="radio" value="August 28th, 2015 8:30AM" name="paramedic30hournccpcoursedate" /><label>August 27th, 2015 8:30AM</label><br />
                        <input type="radio" value="December 4th, 2015 8:30AM" name="paramedic30hournccpcoursedate" /><label>December 4th, 2015 8:30AM</label><br />
                        <input type="radio" value="January 14th, 2016 8:30AM" name="paramedic30hournccpcoursedate" /><label>January 14th, 2016 8:30AM</label><br />
                       <input type="radio" value="February 29th, 2016 8:30AM" name="paramedic30hournccpcoursedate" /><label>February 29th, 2016 8:30AM</label><br />
    </tr>
    <tr>                

</tr>                   <tr>                    

                    <td class="left"><label for="aclsinitialcoursedate">2015 ACLS Initial Course Dates:</label></td>
                        <td>
                       <input type="radio" value="6/8 & 6/10 8AM" name="aclsinitialcoursedate" /><label> 6/8 & 6/10 8AM</label><br />
             <input type="radio" value="7/6 & 7/8 8AM" name="aclsinitialcoursedate" /><label> 7/6 & 7/8 8AM</label><br />
             <input type="radio" value="8/3 & 8/5 8AM" name="aclsinitialcoursedate" /><label> 8/3 & 8/5 8AM</label><br/>
             <input type="radio" value="9/18 & 9/25 8AM" name="aclsinitialcoursedate" /><label> 9/18 & 9/25 8AM</label><br />
         <input type="radio" value="11/6 & 11/13 8AM" name="aclsinitialcoursedate" /><label> 11/6 & 11/13 8AM</label><br /> 
                    <tr>                

                    <td class="left"><label for="aclsrecertcoursedate">2015 ACLS Recert Course Dates:</label></td>
                        <td>
                       <input type="radio" value="6/15 8AM" name="aclsrecertcoursedate" /><label> 6/15 8AM</label><br />
             <input type="radio" value="7/13 8AM" name="aclsrecertcoursedate" /><label> 7/13 8AM</label><br />
             <input type="radio" value="10/2 8AM" name="aclsrecertcoursedate" /><label> 10/2 8AM</label><br/>
             <input type="radio" value="11/20 8AM" name="aclsrecertcoursedate" /><label> 11/20 8AM</label><br/>     
    </tr>
    <tr>                

            <td class="left"><label for="palsinitialcoursedate">2015 PALS Initial Course Dates:</label></td>
                        <td>
                       <input type="radio" value="6/22 & 6/24 8AM" name="palsinitialcoursedate" /><label> 6/22 & 6/24 8AM</label><br />
             <input type="radio" value="7/20 & 7/22 8AM" name="palsinitialcoursedate" /><label> 7/20 & 7/22 8AM</label><br />
             <input type="radio" value="8/10 & 8/12 8AM" name="palsinitialcoursedate" /><label> 8/10 & 8/12 8AM</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" value="10/9 & 10/16 8AM" name="palsinitialcoursedate" /><label> 10/9 & 10/16 8AM</label><br/>        
                    <tr>                    

                    <td class="left"><label for="palsrecertcoursedate">2015 PALS Recert Course Dates:</label></td>
                        <td>
                       <input type="radio" value="6/29 8AM" name="palsrecertcoursedate" /><label> 6/29 8AM</label><br />
             <input type="radio" value="7/27 8AM" name="palsrecertcoursedate" /><label> 7/27 8AM</label><br />
             <input type="radio" value="10/23 8AM" name="palsrecertcoursedate" /><label> 10/23 8AM</label><br/>
             </td>  

                                                    <tr>



                </table>

                <div id="captcha-area" style="margin-left: 130px;">

                <?php

                require_once('recaptchalib.php');
                $publickey = "edited out for example";
                $privatekey = "edited out for example";

                # the response from reCAPTCHA
                $resp = null;
                # the error code from reCAPTCHA, if any
                $error = null;

                # are we submitting the page?
                if ($_POST["submit"]) {
                  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                                  $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                                  $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                                  $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

                  if ($resp->is_valid) {
                    echo "You got it!";
                    # in a real application, you should send an email, create an account, etc
                  } else {
                    # set the error code so that we can display it. You could also use
                    # die ("reCAPTCHA failed"), but using the error message is
                    # more user friendly
                    $error = $resp->error;
                  }
                }
                echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error);
                ?>

                </div>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
            </form>
```

Here is contactengine.php:

```
<?php

require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "key removed intentionally for example";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
  die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
       "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
}

$EmailFrom = "email@address.com";
$EmailTo = "email@address.com";
$Subject = "Refresher Form Submission";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$EMT = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['EMT'])); 
$NREMT = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['NREMT'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Phone = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Phone'])); 
$Address = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Address'])); 
$Program = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Program'])); 
$nccrtraining = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['NCCR Training'])); 
$Operating = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Operating']));
$emt20hournccpcoursedate = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['EMT 20 Hour NCCP Course Date:']));  
$paramedic30hournccpcoursedate = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Paramedic 30 Hour NCCP Course Date']));  
$aclsinitialcoursedate = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['ACLS Initial Course Date']));  
$aclsrecertcoursedate = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['ACLS Recert Course Date']));  
$palsinitialcoursedate = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['PALS Initial Course Date']));  
$palsrecertcoursedate = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['2015 PALS Recert Course Dates:']));  

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "EMT: ";
$Body .= $EMT;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "NREMT: ";
$Body .= $NREMT;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Phone: ";
$Body .= $Phone;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Address: ";
$Body .= $Address;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Program: ";
$Body .= $Program;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "NCCR Training: ";
$Body .= $nccrtraining;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Operating: ";
$Body .= $Operating;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "EMT 20 Hour NCCP Course Date: ";
$Body .= $emt20hournccpcoursedate;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Paramedic 30 Hour NCCP Course Date: ";
$Body .= $paramedic30hournccpcoursedate;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "ACLS Initial Course Date: ";
$Body .= $aclsinitialcoursedate;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "ACLS Recert Course Date: ";
$Body .= $aclsrecertcoursedate;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "PALS Initial Course Date: ";
$Body .= $palsinitialcoursedate;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "2015 PALS Recert Course Dates: ";
$Body .= $palsrecertlcoursedate;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=payment.html\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

On my end when I fill out the form I receive the following emailed to me:

```
Name: Firstname Lastname
EMT: 12345
NREMT: 123456
Email: email@address.com
Phone: 5555555555
Address: Full address
Program: EMT NCCR
NCCR Training:
Operating: Windows
EMT 20 Hour NCCP Course Date:
Paramedic 30 Hour NCCP Course Date:
ACLS Initial Course Date:
ACLS Recert Course Date:
PALS Initial Course Date:
2015 PALS Recert Course Dates:
```

The fields NCCR Training, EMT 20 Hour NCCP Course Date, Paramedic 30 Hour NCCP Course Date, ACLS Initial Course Date, ACLS Recert Course Date, PALS Initial Course Date and 2015 PALS Recert Course Dates are completely blank. But the other fields are fine. As far as I can tell all the fields are configured in the same way.

Thoughts? Please and thank you, Stackoverflow.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Because you're not targeting the correct attribute. You need to use each form element's name attribute, so for example, `$_POST['NCCR Training'])` is wrong and should be `$_POST['nccrtraining'])`

Comment: for one thing `aclsinitialcoursedate` / `name="aclsrecertcoursedate"` != `ACLS Initial Course Date` / `$_POST['ACLS Initial Course Date']` - voted to close, it's a debugging question. Use error reporting to do that.

Comment: There are too many problems to salvage, next question please :D

Comment: @shehary actually, no. there was a simple solution. the script may not be elegant and contain errors (it's not mine) but it works with another answer posted elsewhere. "there are too many problems to salvage" is not a helpful answer for anyone.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're not targeting the correct attribute. You need to use each form element's name attribute, so for example, `$_POST['NCCR Training'])` is wrong and should be `$_POST['nccrtraining'])`

Comment: along with others. OP's got their work cut out ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah I'm not going through and listing each one ;) We'll leave that as an exercise for the OP.

Comment: No better way to *feed* a person, then to "show them *how* to fish" ;-)

Comment: This is extremely helpful, thank you. I sincerely appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

you are missing to add the names in collecting the post data,try to change,

```
$_POST['NCCR Training'] to $_POST['nccrtraining']

$_POST['EMT 20 Hour NCCP Course Date'] to $_POST['emt20hournccpcoursedate']

$_POST['Paramedic 30 Hour NCCP Course '] to _POST['paramedic30hournccpcoursedate']

$_POST['ACLS Initial Course Date'] to $_POST['aclsinitialcoursedate']

$_POST['ACLS Initial Course Date'] to $_POST['aclsrecertcoursedate']

$_POST['PALS Initial Course Date'] to $_POST['palsinitialcoursedate']
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.